# App flickers in android task manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, taskmanager

I recently noticed a weird flickering that occurs when my app is presented in the android "task manager".

It seems like the activity is drawn on top of the navigation bar for a short time and then pushed back.
When other apps are opened, my app appears in front of all others and the "flickers" back.

Here are some screencasts:

- https://youtu.be/tFPurqa7aww (Without other apps)
- https://youtu.be/XeHi4NINwCQ (With another app opened)

My `activity_main.xml` layout file implements a simple navigation drawer with an empty `FrameLayout` that is replaced with the current fragment:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        app:insetForeground="@color/insetsForeground">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            tools:context="NavDrawerAdapter" />

    </ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and knows how to solve it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've just found the issue. It was due to my window background being set to `@android:color/transparent` in my application theme.

Somehow this made the whole activity disappear in the task manager.